# Density of states dependence on bandwidth (Solid State)

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

For a general metal band structure, if the bandwidth is smaller, and the band is flatter, does it imply a larger density of states? 
I was told that the stoner criterion is satisfied for a larger density of states, with a smaller band width? Why?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct. The density of states really measures the number of states in a small energy range. Therefore, flatter bands will have more states over a small energy range compared to a highly dispersive band. Said another way, if the orbitals are pretty localized, the effective mass is higher, leading to a large number of states over a small energy range.